# aligning a lot of divs in the centre of the page, is there an easier way?

Tags: html, css

My code looks like:

```
<div id="divone"><div class="content">Content here</div></div>
<div id="divtwo"><div class="content">Content here</div></div>
<div id="divthree"><div class="content">Content here</div></div>
<div id="divfour"><div class="content">Content here</div></div>
<div id="divfive"><div class="content">Content here</div></div>
<div id="divsix"><div class="content">Content here</div></div>
```

The css:

```
.content { width:960px; margin:auto;}
#divone { background-image: url(bg1.png); background-repeat: repeat;}
#divtwo { background-image: url(bg2.png); background-repeat: repeat;}
#divthree { background-image: url(bg1.png); background-repeat: repeat;}
#divfour { background-image: url(bg1.png); background-repeat: repeat;}
#divfive { background-image: url(bg1.png); background-repeat: repeat;}
#divsix { background-image: url(bg1.png); background-repeat: repeat;}
```

I made a jsfiddle to give you an idea of what I'm doing http://jsfiddle.net/64H5p/

Is there an easier way without adding the `.content` every time I want the div aligning to the centre? The site I'm working on has about 100 of these per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your css code

```
div[id^='div'] div { 
  width:120px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/64H5p/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a container div, center that with margin: 0 auto and then put the divs inside, each with 100% width

Answer (score 0):

why not just use `text-align:center;` on each outer wrapper div? (divone, divtwo, ...)

Comment: The content isn't always text.

Comment: the text-align property will align non-text content, could you give a more full example?

Answer (score 0):

```
 #divone, #divtwo, #divthree, #divfour, #divfive, #divsix {
     width:960px; 
     margin:0 auto;
 }
```

You can combine selectors.

And if you still want to have a `div` within the `#divone`, `#divtwo` you can use a selector like this: `#divone div, #divtwo div, #divthree div, ... {}`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/64H5p/2/)

Comment: They have background images that run 100% of the page, and just the content in the internal div is centered, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: See the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made this jfiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/4V68d/

Take a look

Or look here:

```
<div class="content">
<div id="divone">Content here</div>
<div id="divtwo">Content here</div>
<div id="divthree">Content here</div>
<div id="divfour">Content here</div>
<div id="divfive">Content here</div>
<div id="divsix">Content here</div>
</div>​

.content {margin:auto;}
.content div{text-align: center;}
#divone { background-image: url(bg1.png); background-repeat: repeat; background-color:red;}
#divtwo { background-image: url(bg2.png); background-repeat: repeat;background-color:blue;}
#divthree { background-image: url(bg1.png); background-repeat: repeat;background-color:yellow;}
#divfour { background-image: url(bg1.png); background-repeat: repeat;background-color:green;}
#divfive { background-image: url(bg1.png); background-repeat: repeat;background-color:pink;}
#divsix { background-image: url(bg1.png); background-repeat: repeat;background-color:grey;}​
```

If you want that only **some** of them are aligned to the center, add a class to the divs that you want to align to the center

like:

```
<div id="divone" class="centered">Content here</div>

.centered {margin: 0px auto;}
```

Comment: Answers are expected to be self-contained and not rely that a link stays alive to remain useful.